# Format JavaFX Listview using HTML

Tags: java, list, javafx-2

In a Swing JList, it's easy to format the items using simple HTML, for instance:

```
list.getModel().add("<html><b>BOLOD</b></html>");
```

However, doing this in JavaFX results in the raw HTML being displayed. Is there an equivalent functionality for doing this in JavaFX (2) and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While FX ListView doesn't support html formatting you can achieve even more convenient formatting using css styles and classes, see next example:

```
ObservableList<Text> items = FXCollections.<Text>observableArrayList();

items.add(TextBuilder.create().text("BOLD").style("-fx-font-weight:bold;").build());
// or you can aggregate similar styles in stylesheet and use classname:
items.add(TextBuilder.create().text("BOLD2").styleClass("myClassBoldText").build());
items.add(new Text("regular"));

list.setItems(items);
```